datasets package from pip causing a segfault on MacOS?
I'm using pip version 24.1.2 and Python 3.12.4. The installation seemingly goes fine. However, when importing the package, like in the line
from datasets import load_dataset

I'll see
zsh: segmentation fault

just from the import line. I've tried on virtual environments but am encountering the same thing. The Conda installation works, but I'd like to use pip if at all possible. I see similar questions have been asked before, but not in nearly seven years, and the accepted answer suggested a problem with the package itself.

At least one of dataset's dependencies (pyarrow for example) is incompatible with recent versions of pip. Specifying an earlier version during installation solves the issue. pip3.9 worked for me.
